# Create multiple dataframes based on combinations of select columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a large dataframe of coders that rated of a construct of interest. Ultimately, I want to run kappa reliability on each coder pair (and then take weighted mean). First, I need to find a way to take the single dataframe below (test_data) and create multiple dataframes of each combination of coders (pair1, pair2, pair3, etc.) that I will ultimately run through a larger function that assess kappa reliability.

```
test_data <- data.frame(turn = c("s1: text string", "s2: text string" , "s1: text string", "s2: text string", "s1: text string", "s2: text string", "s1: text string"),
                        id = c(12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 17, 17),
                        coder1_1 = c("high", "low", "med", "high", "high", "high", "low"),
                        coder2_1 = c("high", "low", "med", "high", "med", "high", "low"),
                        coder3_1 = c("med", "med", "med", "high", "low", "high", "med"),
                        coder4_1 = c("high", "low", "med", "high", "med", "high", "low")
)
```

I'd like to create 6 separate dataframes of each coder pair while preserving the first two columns (`turn` & `id`) in each dataframe.

For example, dataframe 'pair1' would be:

```
             turn id coder1_1 coder2_1 
1 s1: text string 12     high     high
2 s2: text string 12      low      low
3 s1: text string 12      med      med
4 s2: text string 15     high     high
5 s1: text string 15     high      med
6 s2: text string 17     high     high
7 s1: text string 17      low      low
```

And the next dataframe would be 'pair2':

```
             turn id coder1_1 coder3_1 
1 s1: text string 12     high      med
2 s2: text string 12      low      med
3 s1: text string 12      med      med
4 s2: text string 15     high     high
5 s1: text string 15     high      low
6 s2: text string 17     high     high
7 s1: text string 17      low      med
```

etc... throughout all dyadic comparisons across the four coders (6 total).

I had limited success with `combn(names(test_data[,c(3:6)]),2,simplify=FALSE)` given this just created a list of the column names and didn't retain `turn` and `id`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `combn` on the data itself and then `cbind` the first two columns by making uses of the `FUN`

```
combn(test_data[3:6], 2, simplify = FALSE, 
        FUN = function(x) cbind(test_data[1:2], x))
#[[1]]
#             turn id coder1_1 coder2_1
#1 s1: text string 12     high     high
#2 s2: text string 12      low      low
#3 s1: text string 12      med      med
#4 s2: text string 15     high     high
#5 s1: text string 15     high      med
#6 s2: text string 17     high     high
#7 s1: text string 17      low      low

#[[2]]
#             turn id coder1_1 coder3_1
#1 s1: text string 12     high      med
#2 s2: text string 12      low      med
#3 s1: text string 12      med      med
#4 s2: text string 15     high     high
#5 s1: text string 15     high      low
#6 s2: text string 17     high     high
#7 s1: text string 17      low      med

#[[3]]
#             turn id coder1_1 coder4_1
#1 s1: text string 12     high     high
#2 s2: text string 12      low      low
#3 s1: text string 12      med      med
#4 s2: text string 15     high     high
#5 s1: text string 15     high      med
#6 s2: text string 17     high     high
#7 s1: text string 17      low      low

#...
```

Comment: thank you. one additional question. if I wanted to do list-wise deletion of missing values on each of the 6 dataframes how would I include that in the function above? I tried drop_na(x) with no luck.

Comment: @bpace If the intention is to remove rows having any NA, then wrap with `na.omit` `combn(test_data[3:6], 2, simplify = FALSE, 
        FUN = function(x) na.omit(cbind(test_data[1:2], x)))`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```r
pairs <- combn(grep("coder", colnames(test_data), value = TRUE), 2, simplify = FALSE)
str(pairs)
# List of 6
#  $ : chr [1:2] "coder1_1" "coder2_1"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "coder1_1" "coder3_1"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "coder1_1" "coder4_1"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "coder2_1" "coder3_1"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "coder2_1" "coder4_1"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "coder3_1" "coder4_1"

lapply(pairs, function(p) test_data[,c("turn", "id", p)])
# [[1]]
#              turn id coder1_1 coder2_1
# 1 s1: text string 12     high     high
# 2 s2: text string 12      low      low
# 3 s1: text string 12      med      med
# 4 s2: text string 15     high     high
# 5 s1: text string 15     high      med
# 6 s2: text string 17     high     high
# 7 s1: text string 17      low      low
# [[2]]
#              turn id coder1_1 coder3_1
# 1 s1: text string 12     high      med
# 2 s2: text string 12      low      med
### ...
```

Or using the `combn` on a `list` trick from @akrun's answer,

```r
lapply(combn(test_data[,3:6], 2, simplify = FALSE),
       cbind, test_data[,1:2])
```

Comment: your second answer is similar to `combn(test_data[,3:6], 2, cbind, FALSE, test_data[,1:2])` I do not think you need lapply

Comment: Good point ... I have not typically used `FUN=` in `combn`, so it wasn't the first to come to mind. Thanks.